# proxy for scale, performance (to load external content)?

Tags: proxy

I am sure answer for this question will be very subjective, I simply want to know what the options are out there (for building a proxy to load external contents).

Typically I used cURL in php and pass a variable like proxy.url to fetch content. Then make an AJAX call with Javascript to populate the contents.

EDIT: 
YQL (Yahoo Query language) seems a very promising solution to me, however, it has a daily usage limit which essentially prevents me from using it for large scale projects.

What other options do I have? I am open to any language, any platform, key criteria are: performance and scalability.

Please share your ideas, thoughts and experience on this topic.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

you dont need a proxy server or something else.
Just create a cronjob to fetch the contents every 5 minutes (or whenever you want).

You just need to create a script that grabs the content from the web and saves it (to a file, a database, ...), which will be started by the cronjob.

If somebody requests your page, you just need to send the cached content out and do with it whatever you want to do.

I think scalability and performance will be no problem.

Comment: cronjobs won't work in my case, as I need to fetch content in real time to do data manipulations.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you need to do with the content, you might consider Erlang. It's lightening fast, ridiculously reliable, and great for scaling.

Comment: I basically need to fetch everything per the given url (including css, javascript etc). Erlang is just the language, any built proxy out there? Can you tell me more about your experience on using Erlang vs other languages such as C#, PHP, Java, ruby?